# Make Javascript Line break when window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

```
var popupWindow = window.open('','null','location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=0,scrollbars=0');
var previewMsg = 
    'ID: ' + data.template.MsgID + '\n' +
    'Message Body: ' + data.template.MsgContents + '\n';
    popupWindow.document.write(previewMsg);
```

I am trying to add a line break as you can see by the '\n'. I've tried '\n\n', '\r'. Does not seem to stick when the pop up opens.

Comment: How about you use proper HTML markup since that is what you are working with.

Comment: @epascarello a concrete example of such HTML would be more constructive `:)`

Answer (score 2):

HTML does not normally use `\r` nor `\n` to represent line breaks. Try wrapping each section in a block-level element such as a `<div>` or `<p>`, or using the `<br/>` tag, which is the closest thing you'll get to a line break in HTML, though it's not terribly semantic.

Alternately, use CSS:

```
some-selector {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I feel silly for not trying to wrap them in divs now! Thanks. That worked.